# Calling method from another class to get x and y issue

Tags: java, bluej

Apologies if the title is not appropriate, was having trouble what to call this.

Scenario:
I have a universe type project in java where there are different types of things you can find in a universe (stars, planets, comets etc).

*This is part of my university coursework and I'm stuck on one part*

I have a class called Space_Object which is a superclass and all things found in the universe inherit it. The superclass has variables such as xPosition, yPosition.

I am currently stuck on trying to get **planets** to orbit around **stars**. I am trying to get the x,y coordinates of a star so that the planet can orbit around it (there can be multiple planets and stars). Right now I am passing the star that the planet will orbit around as a field whenever making a new planet.

I created getters inside of Planet to retrieve the x,y of the Star (which works). I am stuck on how can I use that x and y to alter the starting point of the planet. This is what I added to Universe class:

```
public void setCoordsOfPlanet(Planet planetObj)
{
    planetObj.xPosition = planetObj.getSolarSystemX();
}
```

Which gave me an error of:

> xPosition has private access in Space_Object

I am not allowed to make any of the fields public.

Planet class:

```
public class Planet extends Space_Object
{
private int distanceFromStar;
private int orbitSpeed;
static Star solarSystem;


public Planet(int disFromStar, int orbSpeed, Star solSystem, int objectDiameter, Color objectColor, Universe theUniverse)
{

    super(0, 0, 0, 0, objectDiameter, objectColor, theUniverse);
    distanceFromStar = disFromStar;
    orbitSpeed = orbSpeed;
    solarSystem = solSystem;     
}

public int getSolarSystemX ()
{
     return solarSystem.getXPosition();
}

public int getSolarSystemY ()
{
    return solarSystem.getYPosition();
}
}
```

Just in case, the Space_Object constructor:

```
public Space_Object(int xPos, int yPos, int xVel, int yVel, int objectDiameter, Color objectColor, Universe theUniverse)
{
    xPosition = xPos;
    yPosition = yPos;
    xSpeed = xVel;
    ySpeed = yVel;
    color = objectColor;
    diameter = objectDiameter;
    universe = theUniverse;
    universeHeight = universe.getUniverseHeight();
    universeWidth = universe.getUniverseWidth();
    lifeTime = 1000000;

}
```

Am I approaching this from the completely wrong angle? I been trying to change things regarding this matter for past three hours and made no progress - any help is appreciated. If you need more code let me know.

PS: All items in the universe are objects and are represented as colour circles on a canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how do I modify `private` fields from another class: then all you need to do is to add setter methods in your `Space_Object` or `Planet` class, for example:

```
public class Planet {
...
public setCoor(int x, int y) {
    this.xPosition = x;
    this.yPosition = y;
}
}
```

Now you can call this method from the `Star` class: `planet.setCoor(x, y)`

If you want this method to only be accessible from classes of the same package only, remove `public`.

Comment: Works like a charm, the answer was simple yet I couldn't get it right. Thanks for the fast response too :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here.

1. Programming stuff
2. Model of planetary rotation
3. Use of 'Solar System' when it should be 'Star System' :-) The Solar System is our star system; that's because our star is "Sol"

A1. You need xposition to have a method to set it.
A2a. There are no x and y for our solar system or even a star system. If you're going to model spinning galaxies and/or expanding universe (in which case the galaxies also move in 3d space away from each other,) then the star positions (or positions of any object for that matter) are not fixed.
A2b. If you're going with immobile stars and galaxies, a star (not its system) will have an x and a y. 
A2c. A planet revolves around its star in a Kepler orbit with eccentricity greater than 0 and less than 1. To calculate the path, you need axis information for the orbit in addition to the star's location. Wikipedia will have the equations.
A2d. There is no starting position of a planet unless you plan to have planets with unstable orbits. (Or comets which will have their orbits modified during every revolution by the planets they pass by). Planets with stable orbits have always followed and will forever follow the same path (not really, but...) You can place the planet at any point on the orbit and give it appropriate initial velocity (=speed+direction) and watch it go. A3. Self-explanatory

Sounds like a fun project, especially you're animating the model onscreen. In such a case, you also need to decide on your system's clock-speed; the numbers of days that will pass in real time for each second of your simulation time. Additionally, you'll need to select your refresh frequency; how often will you update the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, the universe itself is much simpler than you think it is (in the project spec). All planets orbit around Stars in perfect circles and have a lifespan (1 orbit = 1 life, make object disappear after whatever life span it has). All objects are represented as colour circles on a canvas. Each star will have a static x,y and based on that x,y I will set the x,y of each planet + offset and then calculate the next x,y position for each rotation.